# Getting the process name and printing it out in XV6/C

Tags: c, linux, xv6

I am new to XV6 and trying to figure out how to print out the process name. My initial thought is to get the process id and somehow get the process name from that. Any ideas would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Given that you have a `pid_t` (process ID), for current process via `getpid()`, under linux, you could look under the `/proc/<pid>` directory. That's how linux's `ps` command would do it. xv6/unix-v6 doesn't have that, but, I presume it has a `ps` command. I'd look at the source for the xv6 `ps` command to see what it does. Although I've [personally] used unix-v7 circa 1980 [v6 was already obsolete], I can't remember how it did this. We just used to capture the output of `ps` and parse it.

Answer (score 2):

The structure `struct proc` contains the field `name` which is the process name.

You can hence print it with some code.

Something like:

```
/*The system call*/
/* in sysproc.c*/
int
sys_printname(void){
    int pid;

    /* get syscall argument */
    if (argint(0, &pid) < 0)
        return -1;

    return printname(pid);
}
```

```
/* in proc.c */
int
printname(int pid){
    int found = 0;
    struct proc *p;
    char name[16];

    /* search for the wanted process */
    acquire(&ptable.lock);
    for (p = ptable.proc; p < &ptable.proc[NPROC]; p++) {
        if (p->pid == pid) {
            /* found */
            found = 1;
            /* copy string to our buffer. */
            safestrcpy(name, p->name, sizeof name);
            break;
        }
    }

    release(&ptable.lock);

    if (!found)
        return -2;

    cprintf("%d: %s\n", pid, name);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't forget to update files: (see how other syscall are implemented)

- `syscall.c`
- `syscall.h`
- `usys.S`
- `user.h`

Then you can use your syscall in a program:

`pname.c` (a quick copy of kill.c)

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;

  if(argc < 2){
    printf(2, "usage: pname pid...\n");
    exit();
  }
  for(i=1; i<argc; i++)
    sys_printname(atoi(argv[i]));
  exit();
}
```

Add it to the `Makefile` (inspired yourself from other user program like `kill`)

`make` and you're done